# Does Slithering Behind You cause the encounter deck's discard pile to be shuffled into it?

Tags: arkham-horror-card-game

[Slithering Behind You](https://arkhamdb.com/card/02146) reads:

> **Revelation** - If Hunting Horror is in play, add 1 doom to it. If Hunting Horror is not in play, search the encounter deck, discard pile, and the void for Hunting Horror and spawn it at your location, engaged with you. Shuffle the encounter deck.

Does it cause the encounter deck's discard pile to be shuffled into it at the end?

Comment: At first glance, I would say "no". The card says what to do, and anything not listed does not happen - at least not as a result of the card.

Comment: Furthermore, it makes sense that only the encounter deck would be shuffled, since the discard and void don't contain any information about future game states.

Comment: If I recall correctly, there are other encounter cards that tell you explicitly to shuffle the encounter discard pile back into the encounter deck. To echo previous commenter, I wouldn't do anything not stated on the card.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it does not. Slithering Behind You interacts with Hunting Horror. If that is not in play yet, it makes sure that that happens - by searching in the available cards, in the discarded cards and in the void.

After searching the Encounter deck, you have seen the order of cards. So that needs to be randomised again. This does nothing with the discard pile.